# Moving The Window Location With X & Y Coordinates

Tags: c#, button, textbox, location

I have 2 textboxes, one for X and one for the Y coordinate.
I want it where the user inters values in X and Y and when they press the button, it moves the window to that location.

I added this:

```
this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1000, 500);
```

to here:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(500, 900);
}
```

and it moves the window perfectly when I press the button.

How can I make the window move to the location entered in the textboxes, that way the user can enter X and Y coordinates and when they hit the button, it moves the window to the location they specified.

Answer (score 1):

In the button click handler, you can get the text from the text boxes and convert the strings to integers.  As the text is coming from user input, it's best to use `TryParse` instead of just `Parse` so you won't get exceptions thrown:

```
int windowX, windowY;

if (Int32.TryParse(txtX.Text, out windowX) &&
    Int32.TryParse(txtY.Text, out windowY))
{
    this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(windowX, windowY);
}
else
{
    // Tell the user they didn't enter a valid number
}
```